# Issue with simple project

Tags: arduino-uno, led, time, millis

I'm new to Arduino and today I have a problem with this code:

```
int led_1 = 10;
int led_2 = 11;
int led_3 = 12;
int button = 3;
int time = 0;
byte val = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(led_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  val = digitalRead(button);

  if (val == HIGH){
    time = millis();
    while (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
      if (millis() - time < 1000) {digitalWrite(led_1, HIGH);}
      else if (millis() -time > 1000 && millis()-time <2000) {digitalWrite(led_2, HIGH);}
      else if (millis()-time >2000) {digitalWrite(led_3, HIGH);}
    }
  } else { 
    time =0;
    digitalWrite(led_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led_3, LOW);
    }
}
```

The code should work like this: If I press the button less than one second, `led_1` will turn on. If I press it between one and two seconds, `led_2` will turn on; and if I press the button more than 2 seconds, `led_3` will turn on. If I don't press a button, the LEDs remain off. The `time` variable is used to take the time when I start to press the button and then the control `millis()- time` should give how long I press the button.

It works for a while, then after a random time (I think) if I push the button, only the `led_3` turns on. Why?

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do. You can't just dump the code on us, an expecting us to decipher what it does. Also, what is a `casual`?

Comment: edited the question with more informations

Comment: Thank you. Just use `unsigned long time = 0;` instead. What I also see, is that led 1 remains on, even if the button is pressed for more that one second. Idem for led 2 after two seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` should be an `unsigned int`.  As soon as `millis` reaches 32768, it will be stored as -32768 in `time`, and your comparisons will not work. This happens after 32.768 seconds.  Here's a short sketch to illustrate:

```
int time = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
}

void loop() {
    time = millis();
    if (time % 1000 == 0) {
      Serial.println( time );
      delay( 2 ); // let millis() increment
    }
}
```

To see the difference, just change the first line to

```
unsigned int time = 0;
```

Note how `time` rolls over to 0 after 65535 (well, only 65000 is printed).

I would recommend using unsigned constants by adding a "U" after the digits: `1000U`.  In your `if` statements, you must cast the `millis` to the same (smaller) type: `(unsigned int)millis()`.  Also, parentheses make the expression more clear:

```
      else if (((unsigned int)millis() - time > 1000U) && ((unsigned int)millis() - tempo < 2000U)) {digitalWrite(led_2, HIGH);}
```

Comment: `32768` will actually become `-32768` not -1. I also think this will create a new problem after 65 seconds. Better to just use the same type that `millis` return. I.e. `unsigned long`.

Comment: Oopsies, edited -1 above.  However, he can use any size of unsigned int.  The key is to compare a difference with the desired interval: `(unsigned int)millis()-start > interval`, all unsigned numbers.  If he were watching for intervals < 256, he could have used `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies,I have solved the problem, but I have a question: I see that `int time` reaches 32768 and then becomes -32768, but after that it returns positive again. If I wait for 65 seconds (so time is positive) the LED still doesn't work. Why?

 What does U mean?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that you need to cast the `millis()` to the smaller type.  My example does an implicit cast by assigning to the smaller `unsigned int`.  Edited answer and comment.

Comment: This is getting a bit silly. Casting the millis to an int?! Just use the proper type that is returned by millis, and use `unsigned long time = 0;`. This makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: If `millis` is called just once and stored in a byte or word, like my example, there is no explicit cast (no impact on readability).  One would normally do this when grabbing a timestamp for comparison.  It *does* change the subtraction and comparison to a smaller type.  When the interval is small and the polling frequency is high, it can have significant run-time savings.  Another handy technique is to use the byte-sized TCNT0 directly and simply compare the elapsed ticks with interval/4.  This allows intervals up to ~1s and is efficient enough to use in an ISR or busy-wait loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems inefficient and there is a `tempo` variable that doesn't appear elsewhere.

```
  if (val == HIGH) {
    time = millis();
    while (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
      int time0=millis();
      if (time0 - time < 1000) {
        digitalWrite(led_1, HIGH);
      } else if (time0 - time < 2000) {
        digitalWrite(led_2, HIGH);
      } else if (time0 - time > 2000) {
        digitalWrite(led_3, HIGH);
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that this code will turn on all LEDs, one by one. If you want to turn off the other, you'll have to had code for that in the tests.